# gridstack basics, how to make the demo work

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, gridstack

Really noob question, but I don't understand what am I doing wrong here ?

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="gridstack.js/dist/gridstack.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="grid-stack">
        <div class="grid-stack-item" 
            data-gs-x="0" data-gs-y="0" 
            data-gs-width="4" data-gs-height="2">
                <div class="grid-stack-item-content"> azazfaz</div>
        </div>
        <div class="grid-stack-item" 
            data-gs-x="4" data-gs-y="0" 
            data-gs-width="4" data-gs-height="4">
                <div class="grid-stack-item-content"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0-alpha1/jquery.min.js"> </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/3.10.1/lodash.min.js"> </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="gridstack.js/dist/gridstack.js"> </script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        var options = {
            cell_height: 80,
            vertical_margin: 10
        };
        $('.grid-stack').gridstack(options);
    });
</script>
```

I get this error:

```
gridstack.js:391 Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

pointing to this line in gridstack:

```
  var is_nested = this.container.closest('.' + opts.item_class).size() > 0;
```

EDIT:
I found the problem, if I replace this lines

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0-alpha1/jquery.min.js"> </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

by

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

then it works , any idea why ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery 3.0 removes the jQuery.fn.size method. It's probably safer to just stick with 1.11.x when using this library.

https://github.com/jquery/jquery/issues/1749

(BTW I actually get this.container.closest(...).size is not a function as the reported error).

Comment: just fixed this issue :)

Answer (score 6):

As a workaround, you can do the following to make gridstack work when the `size()` function doesn't exist:

```
$.fn.size = function(){
  return this.length;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery 3.0 and above if you make an edit to gridstack.js as suggested by https://api.jquery.com/size/

Change Line 511 in gridstack.js (version 0.2.5) from:

```
var isNested = this.container.closest('.' + opts.itemClass).size() > 0;
```

to

```
var isNested = this.container.closest('.' + opts.itemClass).length > 0;
```

and gridstack works fine.